# How do I configure XInput so it pressing a button toggles scrolling?

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll, xinput

I followed the instructions found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Logitech_Marblemouse_USB)  to setup my  Logitech TrackMan Marble Mouse.

It works well enough, but I am just wondering if there is a way to use the button(9) as a toggle instead of having to hold it down to scroll?

What I want it to do is this:  Pressing the button(9) toggles the scroll function, so moving the trackball scrolls.  Pressing it again toggles the scroll, and the mouse moves the mouse pointer normally.

Can this be done?  I tried reading up on XInput but all the docs I have read so far does not have anything close to what I want to do.